# Getting Large External Data set into SharePoint list

Tags: 2010, external-content-type, import, external-list

I have a list of "Customers" in a SQL database table with some very basic data:Id, Name, DoB, Mobile, Email, CusotmerType.

There are currently about 80,000 customers

I wanted to use an External Content Type/External Content List to link a list to the table...and while this works, I've hit the 2,000 throttle limit.

Is there a way I can regularly, on a schedule, "import" or "create" this list so that i can get around the limit?  80,000 is not really a LOT of data!

I would prefer to use only SPD or the browser Admin pages to do this - I need to keep any custom code to an absolute minimum as I am the only support member of staff!

The data is only refreshed nightly, so a schedule would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this article to resolve the throttle issue. It is by design to prevent DoS attacks, but you can change the behavior

http://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/crmtechnical/b/marcellotonarelli/archive/2012/06/06/how-to-resolve-2000-items-resolution-in-sharepoint-business-connectivity-services-bcs.aspx

Comment: Thanks - I will do that for now.  However, is there a way to one-off populate SharePoint Lists?  I think this may be a useful thing to know!  [Coming from SalesForce where you can do this kind of thing.]

Comment: That's possible as well. You can use Powershell or export your data from external source and then import it into SharePoint list. You will find lots of example code on web to that.